# Meta key getting stuck in Windows 11 WslG, how to release meta when switching to frame

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, pgtk

In Windows 11 WSL Ubuntu 20.04, I am using the new WslG feature which allows native gtk apps to run smoothly on windows (and I compiled Emacs 29 with the `--with-pgtk` option when installing), but I am running into the Alt (Meta) key randomly being stuck.

This most often occurs in this case (Alt+Tab is the shortcut to switch windows in Windows 11):

1. Launch Emacs
2. While active application is Emacs, use Alt+Tab to switch to the browser application
3. Use Alt+Tab once more to switch back to Emacs
4. Meta key is stuck in Emacs. E.g. just pressing `x` registers as `M-x` in Emacs

I have been able to get around the problem by pressing both Alt keys together, which returns emacs to the "normal" state in some cases, sometimes I have to repeat it a few times though. Is there some way to have Emacs automatically press both Alt (Meta) keys whenever I switch to the Emacs frame? Or some other elegant solution?

Comment: Are you sure it’s not just a sticky key on your keyboard?

Comment: @db48x yes, alt (meta) key works everywhere else. It's probably a bug with how WSLg is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in WSLg. See the opened issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/162